# WPF - Remove event handler are registered by EventManager

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, events

I want to remove event handler are registered with following code

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TreeViewItem),
       Mouse.MouseDownEvent,
       new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnMouseButtonDown),
       true);
```

see [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/TreeViewItem.cs,49) .NET sourse

The method 'OnMouseButtonDown' very bad for me, because the method 'OnMouseButtonDown' calls to 'HandleMouseButtonDown' method, he bring to view the selected tree item when user clicks on triangle in the not selected item or clicks right mouse button.

When a user clicks on the triangle, I want tree item just opens, but will not change the selected item, and not scroll the view to selected item. Now because 'HandleMouseButtonDown' the view moves to selected item, and the user loses the item clicked on it.

So how can I remove this event handler?

Answer (score 0):

In my view, it is better to suppress your `PreviewMouseDown` event of TreeViewItem like so:

```
   <TreeView TreeViewItem.PreviewMouseDown="TreeViewItem_PreviewMouseDown">
        <TreeViewItem Header="1" IsExpanded="True" >
            <TreeViewItem Header="2.1" >
                <TreeViewItem Header="An Item" />
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="2.2">
                <TreeViewItem Header="An Item" />
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="3.2">
                <TreeViewItem Header="An Item" />
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>

private void TreeViewItem_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   //this will suppress the event
   //e.Handled = true;
   //instead of suppressing the event you can put your logic here to avoid  what you want
}
```

Comment: I added a breakpoint on `e.Handled = true;` and it's never stopped.
 must use `PreviewMouseDown` Instead, but then can`t open tree items.

Comment: @codeDom What is your goal by removing event handler?

Comment: the method 'OnMouseButtonDown' calls to ['HandleMouseButtonDown'](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/TreeView.cs,371)  method, this method is bad for me because he bring to view the selected tree item when user clicks on triangle in the not selected item or clicks right mouse button.

Comment: @codeDom you do not want SelectedTreeViewItem to be selected when an user clicks at the triangle?

Comment: When a user clicks on the triangle, I want tree item just opens, but will not change the selected item, and not scroll the view to selected item. Now because 'HandleMouseButtonDown' the view moves to selected item, and the user loses the item clicked on it.